# Passing object from function to another function

Tags: php, function

Here's the situation i'm passing a object through several php functions.
I m looking for the best performance so i was wondering is serialization a good way to do it or is serialization not necessary?

Comment: Firstly, there is not nearly enough information here for this question to get a fully considered useful answer. Secondly, I would be *very* surprised if serialization was a good idea here. You are adding pointless overhead.

Comment: Why would you need to serialize the object to pass it from one function to another?  Can you show an example of what you're doing?

Comment: Please show what you have tried??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are passing an object through several 'functions' then you don't need to serialise - this will be in memory in the PHP parser and serialization will just be a waste.

If you need to pass the value from one script page to another, then serialization is an option as the variables in the first script will be out of scope in the second script.

Most of the time you don't need to do this - what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the object. You don't need serialization.

```
function foo() {
    return new Foo;
}

function bar($obj) {
    return $obj;
}

function baz($obj) {
    $obj->foo();
}

baz(bar(foo()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Serialization is one of the worst things you can do. Objects in php 5 are passed by reference and this way the amount of data passed between functions is minimal(only a pointer which is an integer).

Comment: In addition, if you unserialize the object within the called function, it will not be the original object but a clone, so any changes made to that object within the function will be to the clone and not to the original instance

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no problem passing objects around like this:

```
$obj=new myclass;
$result=mufunk($obj);

function myfunk($myfobj)
  {
    $myreturn=new anotherclass;
    return $myreturn;
  }
```